# Cannot upload Face Data to Hikvision Camera using SDK

Tags: c++, qt, sdk, hikvision

I am going to use the Face Recognition function in Hikvision Camera using sdk on Qt(c++).
I did try to upload face data to hikvision library but it doesn't work.

Here's my code.

```
    strXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><FaceAppendData><name>%2</name><bornTime>%1</bornTime><sex>%3</sex><province>65</province><certificateType>ID</certificateType><certificateNumber>%4</certificateNumber></FaceAppendData>"
    NET_DVR_SEND_PARAM_IN m_struSendParam = {0};
        pSendAppendData = new BYTE[strXml.size()];
        memcpy(pSendAppendData, strXml.toStdString().c_str(), strXml.size());

        m_struSendParam.dwSendAppendDataLen = strXml.size();
        m_struSendParam.pSendAppendData = pSendAppendData;
//set pic data
    QFile file(m_strFileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "File Read Error", "Cant' read this file.");
        return;
    }
    //pSendPicData = new BYTE[file.size()];
    QByteArray byteData = file.readAll();
    m_struSendParam.dwSendDataLen= byteData.size();
    //memcpy(pSendPicData, byteData.data(), file.size());
    file.close();
    m_struSendParam.pSendData = (BYTE*)byteData.data();
    m_struSendParam.byPicType = 1;
    m_struSendParam.byPicURL = 0;
if (NET_DVR_UploadSend(m_lUploadHandle, &m_struSendParam, NULL) < 0){
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error", QString("Upload failed.\nError Code: %1").arg(NET_DVR_GetLastError()));
    }while (1) {
        LONG iStatus = getUploadState();
        if (iStatus == 1) {//Uploaded
            stopUploadData();
            accept();
        }
        if (iStatus >= 3) {//Upload failed
            stopUploadData();
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "ERROR", QString("Upload Failed. Status Code: %1").arg(iStatus));
            break;
        }
    }
```

The result is "Upload Failed".

Please help me with what is not correct.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of creating your own error messages, doesn't the API have functions to return to you the last error that occurred as a number and/or a string defined inside the library?  Just having an "Upload Failed" is rather poor, if that is all the library offers you for error checking.

Comment: There are many status codes.
My Status Code: 3(Upload Failed).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please check the isapi protocol here